# Jetpack Compose - Toast message is showing only once

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to show toast message which is updating when API call is called within ViewModel and display message on screen.

But for some reason its displayed only if I update it once.

ViewModel:

```
private val _errorMessage = mutableStateOf<String?>(null)
 val errorMessage: State<String?> = _errorMessage
```

Composable function created to handle Toast:

```
@Composable
private fun ShowError(viewModel: LoginViewModel, context: Context){
    val errorMessage by remember { viewModel.errorMessage }
    errorMessage?.let {
        App.showToast(context, it)
    }
}
```

Its used like this:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun LoginScreen(
    viewModel: LoginViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    navController: NavController,
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val image by viewModel.image.collectAsState(initial = null)
    // UI layout
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            CenterAlignedTopAppBar(title = { Text(text = context.getString(R.string.login_screen_title)) })
        },
        content = {contentPadding ->
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(start = 8.dp, end = 8.dp, top = contentPadding.calculateTopPadding())
            ) {
                //other composable UI components
            }
        }
    )

    App.log("LoginScreen: showToast: composable screen")
    // Handle toast message
    ShowError(viewModel = viewModel, context = context)
}
```

Comment: Use `SharedFlow` instead of `StateFlow`

Answer (score 0):

To show a Toast message in response to state changes in your ViewModel, you should use `LaunchedEffect` within your Composable function `ShowError`. This is because you want the side effect (showing a Toast) to run when certain conditions in your state change.

Here's how you can modify your `ShowError` Composable to use `LaunchedEffect` properly within the Composable:

```kotlin
@Composable
private fun ShowError(viewModel: LoginViewModel) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val errorMessage by viewModel.errorMessage.observeAsState()

    LaunchedEffect(errorMessage) {
        errorMessage?.let {
            Toast.makeText(context, it, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            viewModel.clearErrorMessage()
        }
    }
}
```

And in your `LoginViewModel`, you should add a method to clear the error message after it's been shown, to avoid showing the same message repeatedly every recomposition:

```kotlin
class LoginViewModel : ViewModel() {
    // ...

    private val _errorMessage = mutableStateOf<String?>(null)
    val errorMessage: State<String?> = _errorMessage

    fun clearErrorMessage() {
        _errorMessage.value = null
    }

    // ...
}
```

Make sure that you clear your message in the ViewModel after it's shown, to make sure it does not reappear upon the next recomposition unless a new error message is set.

With these changes, `ShowError` now observes the `errorMessage` state. Whenever `errorMessage` changes and is not `null`, `LaunchedEffect` will execute and show the toast. After the toast is shown, the error message is cleared so that it does not display again unless a new error message is set.

Finally, remove the context parameter from the `ShowError` invocation inside your `LoginScreen` Composable, as it is now unnecessary with the `LocalContext.current` call within the `ShowError` function:

```kotlin
// Within your Scaffold in LoginScreen
ShowError(viewModel = viewModel)
```

This pattern ensures your side effect (showing a toast) responds to state changes instead of relying on the Composable function execution or recomposition, which could lead to unexpected behavior.